# See info about active Artifactory plugins

Tags: artifactory

I started running [this plugin](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup/artifactCleanup) for Artifactory with `http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/plugins/execute/cleanup?params=days=1|repos=project1,project2,project3` after placing the Groovy file in `/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc/plugins`.

Is there anywhere I can look to see log files for this, or anywhere I can look to ensure the plugin is actually running?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In order to see the plugin in the logs, you will need to add the following to the '$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc/logback.xml' file. NO NEED for a restart after adding this, Artifactory will auto-reload the logback:

```
<logger name="YOUR-PLUGIN-NAME">
<level value="info"/>
</logger>
```

Please replace the YOUR-PLUGIN-NAME with the actual plugin name. You can also change the level value to present "debug" or "trace" and to add trace and debug lines in the plugin but that it up to you.